# Prove that the group of diagonal matrices is not a normal subgroup of the group $\mathrm{GL}_n\,(\mathbb K)$ if $n\ge 2$ and $|K|\ge 3$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I tried some numerical examples but have no idea how to prove it in general.

Could some one give me an idea how to prove it?

https://books.google.de/books?id=kd24d3mwaecC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=Vinberg+Prove+that+the+group+of+diagonal+matrices+is+not+a+normal+subgroup+of+the+group&source=bl&ots=Nao4W5dhzd&sig=4CpgVK4OCIEhMSaZH1r8Y1l6oIg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqisLOoaraAhULfFAKHfk_Dc0Q6AEINjAB#v=onepage&q=Vinberg%20Prove%20that%20the%20group%20of%20diagonal%20matrices%20is%20not%20a%20normal%20subgroup%20of%20the%20group&f=false

Comment: Diagonal matrices basically stabilize the collection of 1-dimensional subspaces, each spanned by one of the vectors in a natural basis. Any invertible transformation that disturbs this decomposition will lead to an example. The case $K=\Bbb{F}_2$ is exceptional because the only invertible diagonal matrix is the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $|K|>2$ there exists two distinct non-zero elements in $K$. Say, $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Conjugate the diagonal matrix $D=diag(\alpha,\beta)$ with 
$$P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\ 
0&1\end{array}\right).$$
You get that
$$
PDP^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\alpha&-\alpha+\beta\\0&\beta\end{array}\right).
$$
This is not diagonal because $\alpha\neq \beta$.

For examples with larger matrices just add ones along the diagonal and zeros elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Because$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\1&-1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&1&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&0&1&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&1\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&1&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&0&1&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&1\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\1&-1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&1&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&0&1&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$is equal to$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\1&0&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&1&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&0&1&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&1\end{pmatrix},$$which is not diagonal. Note that if $\operatorname{char}K=2$ then this would fail because then the matrix$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\1&-1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&1&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&0&1&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&1\end{pmatrix}$$wouldn't be invertible.